# Where can 'on update' be used?

Tags: mysql, triggers, onupdate

I need help with `on update` in MySQL.

Currently I need to set up a `created` and `updated` row in a table `documents` that has `keywords` related by a `Foreign Key`.

So I create a trigger for the keywords to update the `updated` time of the related document and I need to create another for `Documents` table.

The question is if I can use `on update` instead of a trigger.

I've tried searching about `on update` statement to see if it refers to the whole record being updated, in how many columns can it be used, etc, but I didn't find any MySQL doc's topic on it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For implementing this issue you don't need to use trigger. That is because `created` has logical meaning to be written once and for all. So you'll pass something like `NOW()` when *inserting* your row.

Now, as for `updated`, which has logical meaning of *last change timestamp* - then with defining timestamp field you can specify [ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) clause:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (   
>   s TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,   
>   dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );
> ```

-that's it. I.e. while in common case for update events you'll have to use triggers, this is the case, when MySQL provides built-in solution. To say more, this *is the case* when you're expected to use that - i.e. that is why it exist in MySQL.

Common answer to question 'when' is opinion based, but implementation of logical 'update date' is the general purpose.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a topic about the `on update` clause? I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: What do you mean 'topic'? You should just search through SO then, if you want. But I think explanations in official manual page is quite enough to clarify general purpose of this feature

Comment: With topic I mean official documentation about what `on update` is, I know its very obvious, but I'd like to see what can I do with it, if it creates a trigger, etc.

Comment: Well, it doesn't (i.e. defining such field will not create similar trigger). Obviously it creates some event-binding inside MySQL implementation on code level, but you can find exact answer only inside source code.